# Using apps script to convert doc to PDF and PDF is coming up blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, export-to-pdf

I am learning the basics here.  Trying to create a google doc then turn it into a PDF. Here's the code:

```
function pdfTesting(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('aaTest');
  
  var docBody = doc.getBody();
  docBody.appendParagraph('test 1');
  docBody.appendParagraph('test 2');

  var docBlob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

  var testFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1wlZio9suu2-TIAGxAbMRAYACCStEDGeK');
  var docPDF = testFolder.createFile(docBlob);

}
```

The doc has the text in it, but the PDF is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function pdfTesting(){
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.folder1id);
  const doc = DocumentApp.create("TestFile");
  const body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph("Text1");
  body.appendParagraph("Text2");
  const id = doc.getId();
  doc.saveAndClose();
  Drive.Files.update({ "parents": [{ "id": folder.getId() }] },doc.getId());
  folder.createFile(DriveApp.getFileById(id).getAs("application/pdf"));
}
```

Comment: `gobj.globals.folder1id`?

Comment: Just a global variable I use.

Comment: SAVE AND CLOSE! That did it. :-)